# Loading pytorch models, test accuracy drops

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I have a PyTorch model that has test accuracy of about 95% - 97%. I save it using torch.save(my_model.state_dict(), PATH), but whenever I try to reload it using `my_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))` and test it on the same data using `test_fn(my_model)` my test accuracy goes down to about 0.06%.I'm trying to follow the suggest serialization semantics (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/serialization.html)

This happens whether or not I use my_model.eval() (although by defualt I'm not using this for either training or testing). Is there an extra step I need to take?

In code this looks like:

```
my_model = GraphConv(w2i, p2i, l2i, r2i, s2i, words, pos, lems, 512, 512, 3) ## Initialise model & params
my_model.cuda()
loss_function = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(my_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(15):
    ...   ### Apply training steps
    print(test_fn(my_model))  ### Will be over 95%
    torch.save(my_model.state_dict(), PATH)

...
my_model2 = GraphConv(w2i, p2i, l2i, r2i, s2i, words, pos, lems, 512, 512, 3) ## Initialise new model
my_model2.load_state_dict(torch.load('PATH'))
print(test_fn(my_model2))  ### Is about 0.06%
```

Comment: You sure applying the same *preprocessing* steps in your data?

Comment: Please share more details about your process with us. Are you using the `model.eval()` flag when you are computing the accuracies (in both cases)? Is there a reason why you don't just load the network with `net = torch.load(checkpoint)`? Can you share a bit of your code?

Comment: I've edited my original question to put some code in.

Comment: I have the same problem. I verified the data preprocessing is the same when I trained the model. Still, there is some drop in accuracy. Any ideas?